# comparing two different type of List using Java8

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
class Person{

private String name;
private String address;
private int id;
private int uniqueIdentificationNumber;

}


class Company{

private String name;
private String address;
private int id;
private int uniqueIdentificationNumber;
private String company;
}


class Test{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
      Person p1 = new Person();
      p1.setName("ABC");
      p1.setAddress("US");
      p1.setId(1);
      p1.setUniqueIdentificationNumber(11);
     
      Person p2 = new Person();
      p2.setName("PQR");
      p2.setAddress("US");
      p2.setId(2);
      p2.setUniqueIdentificationNumber(22);
     
      persons.add(p1);
      persons.add(p2);  

     List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();
     
     Company c1 = new Comapny();
      c1.setName("ABC");
      c1.setAddress("US");
      c1.setId(3);
      c1.setUniqueIdentificationNumber(44);
      c1.setCompany("C1")

     Company c2 = new Comapny();
      c2.setName("ABC");
      c2.setAddress("US");
      c2.setId(1);
      c2.setUniqueIdentificationNumber(11);
      c2.setCompany("C2");

      companies.add(c1);
      companies.add(c2)

}
}
```

I want to compare two  different object types of lists (companies and persons) with **Java8 Stream API** and return the customer object which is matching with Id and setUniqueIdentificationNumber. i.e here in this case it should retun **c2**.

Can anyone help on this

Comment: Do you know how you'd do this if the lists were of the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't clear how `uniqueIdentificationNumber` of the `Person` and `Company` are related. It's worth to **refine** these *classes* to represent the relationship between them in a better way (maybe a company can hold a reference to a list of customers). And don't overuse setters, if **id** is unique there's no need to allow it to be changed.

Although it's not clear how these values are connected because of the drawbacks of your class design technically it's doable.

> return the customer object which is matching with Id

For that, you need to create two **maps** that will associate these *identifiers* with *companies* and *persons*. Then create a stream over the *keys* of one of these *maps* and check for every *key* whether if contained in another *map*. And then retrieve the `Person` objects for filtered keys and collect the result into a list.

```
    Map<Integer, Person> personById =
            persons.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getUniqueIdentificationNumber,
                                              Function.identity()));
    Map<Integer, Company> companyById =
            companies.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Company::getUniqueIdentificationNumber,
                                               Function.identity()));

    List<Person> customers =
            personById.keySet().stream()
                    .filter(companyById::containsKey) // checking whether id is present in the company map
                    .map(personById::get) // retrieving customers
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**Update**

Let me rephrase the description of the problem.

There are two unrelated classes `A` and `B`. Both classes have **two fields** of type `int`, let's say `val1` and `val2` (and maybe a few more fields but we are not interested in them).

We have a list of objects `A` and a list of objects `B`. The goal is to find a single object `A` for which exists an object `B` with the same values for both `val1` and `val2` (in order to keep things simple I propose to stick with this example).

There are two approaches that could be used for that purpose:

- create an auxiliary class with two fields `val1` and `val2`, and associate every instance of `A` and `B` with instances of this class;
- create a nested map `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, *targetClass*>>`, this solution is more complicated and less flexible, if you'll need to compare objects by three, four, etc. fields the code will quickly become incomprehensible.

So I'll stick with the first approach. We need to declare the `ValueHolder` class with two fields and implement the `equals/hashCode` contract based on these fields. For *Java 16* and above we can utilize a **record** for that purpose and make use of `equals()`, `hashCode`, getters provided by the compiler. The option with the record will look like this:

```
public record ValueHolder(int val1, int val2) {} // equals/hashCode, constructor and getters provided by the compiler
```

Classes `A` and `B`

```
public class A {
    private int val1;
    private int val2;

    // constructor and getters
}

public class B {
    private int val1;
    private int val2;

    // constructor and getters
}
```

And a method that accepts two lists: `List<A>` and `List<B>`, and return a result as `Optional<A>`. Because the matching element may or may not be present and it's a good practice to return an optional object in such cases instead of returning `null` in case the result was not found. It provides more flexibility and that's precisely the case for which the optional was designed.

```
public Optional<A> getMatchingItem(List<A> listA, List<B> listB) {

    Map<ValueHolder, A> aByValue = listA.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> new ValueHolder(a.getVal1(), a.getVal2()),
                    Function.identity()));

    Map<ValueHolder, B> bByValue = listB.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> new ValueHolder(b.getVal1(), b.getVal2()),
                    Function.identity()));

    return aByValue.keySet().stream()
            .filter(bByValue::containsKey)
            .findFirst()
            .map(aByValue::get);
}
```

Comment: I aggree there is no relation here, but i used classes just for shairing requirement  . basically i need  to compare two fields from one list of object with other list  object and return matching object of customer.

Comment: @andrew And the solution above doesn't satisfy your requirement? It creates a list of customers (`Person` objects) with the matching value of `id`. Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: No it not, it should create the list of/ returns the complete object of customer where persons id and uniqueIdentificationNumber should match with any of the company's id and uniqueIdentificationNumber

Comment: So need a match based on two field `id` and `uniqueIdentificationNumber`. And the return type will be a `List<Person>`?

Comment: Yes need to match on two field id and uniqueIdemtificationNumber ..Return type will be Company.object .. if that is not possible then atleast List<Company> .. I should get

Comment: @andrew A single `Person`, first encountered in a list that has matching fields with any of the `Company` objects. Or a `List<Company>`, right?

Comment: Yes correct. Whatever is the first match return it.. If first person not matched with any of the company..need to check with second person with all the company object